# Как периодически подставлять данные из localStorage в textArea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, localstorage

Есть 2 страницы. На странице №1 скрипт по клику записывает в localStorage текст ячейки(с этим скриптом проблемы нет)
На странице №2 второй скрипт каждые 100 милисекунд должен проверять содержимое localStorage и добавлять его к содержимому textarea. Почему-то не могу въехать в реализацию. Несмотря на наличие setInterval() скрипт исполняется всего один раз.

Вот сам скрипт.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    setInterval(getSmile(), 100);
});

function getSmile() {
    var text = $('textarea[name="message"]').text();
    var smile = localStorage.getItem('current_smile');
    $('textarea[name="message"]').text(text + " " + smile);
}
```

По хорошему, форма должна просто забиваться содержимым smile, но это не происходит. Что не так?

Comment: Уберите скобки у getSmile. Сейчас напишу почему это не работает в ответе

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Дело в том, что `setInterval` принимает первым аргументом функцию, а вы передаете ему результат её выполнения, т.к. у вас стоят там скобки. Таким образом, вы один раз выполняете `getSmile`, а в интервале пытается запуститься то, что возвращает эта функция (в вашем случае ничего). Правильно будет так -

```
setInterval(getSmile,100) 
//или 
setInterval(function(){ getSmile(); },100)
```

Answer (score 0):

Я не совсем понял зачем вы каждые 100милисекунд опрашивает localStorage

```
if (window.addEventListener) {
  window.addEventListener("storage", onStorageEvent, false);
} else {
   window.attachEvent("onstorage", onStorageEvent);
};

function onStorageEvent(storageEvent){
      getSmile(storageEvent.newValue);
}

function getSmile(smile)
{
   var text = $('textarea[name="message"]').text();
   $('textarea[name="message"]').text(text + " " + smile);
}
```

Дело в том, что у всех браузеров вызывается событие при записи переменной в LocalStorage, повесить на него свой обработчик будет более правильно.

Comment: Ну не совсем. http://caniuse.com/#search=localstorage - вкладка Known issues, пункт 6.

Comment: Спасибо, честно говоря не сталкивался с этой проблемой в IE, Тогда советую для пользователей IE-10, IE-11, использовать механизм опроса, а в других браузерах пользоваться возможностями на все 100.

Comment: Согласен.​​​​​​​